# Why clearTimeout is not preventing the execution of my function in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout

I am trying to execute an API call 3 seconds after the last modification of a variable in Vue.js.

I implemented this using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` with a `watcher` on my variable :

```
data () return {
   timeoutDuration: null,
}

watch: {
   queryGeocodage: function (value) {
        if (this.timeoutDuration) clearTimeout(this.timeoutDuration)
        await // async stuff
        this.timeoutDuration = setTimeout(() => { console.log('timeout') }, 2000)
   }
```

}

The `console.log` still execute as many time as `queryGeocodage` change like if the timeout wasn't clear.

Why the timeout isn't cleared?

Comment: Because after **clearTimeout** you set it again **this.timeoutDuration = setTimeout...**

Comment: Yes but that should make the console.log execute once isn't it?

Comment: Maybe **queryGeocodage** changes several times for 2 seconds, and change it to be **async function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess:

Because queryGeocodage() is async function, when queryGeocodage change before `await // async stuff` completed, this.timeoutDuration is not assgined. So clearTimeout() is not executed.

You can try to log the value of this.timeoutDuration to explore it.